# Lexical scoping in ES6 / Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, scoping, lexical

I'm attempting to understand ES6 lexical scoping (using the node runtime).
Consider the following:

```
'use strict';
let x = 10;
function f() {
   console.log(x);
   console.log(y); // This should crash
}

let y = 5;
f();
```

Paraphrasing from the O'Reilly book "Learning Javascript":

> Lexical scoping means whatever variables are in scope where you define a function from (as opposed to when you call it) are in scope in the function.

However, when I run this program (via node), it outputs:
10
5

Isn't the call to console.log(y) breaking the lexical scoping rules here? If not, why not?

Edit: For future reference, it appears that the author of the textbook (Learning Javascript 3rd Edition O'Reilly) has recently listed this example as an error in the "Confirmed Errata". on http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920035534

Comment: Variable declarations are hoisted to the beginning of the block.

Comment: @Barmar if you access a `let` before its definition you'd get a temporal dead zone error. If you invert the `let y = 5;` and the `f()` you get an error - not `undefined` logged.

Comment: He's not accessing it until he calls `f()`, which is after the variable is initialized.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It's a *temporal* dead zone, not a *lexical* dead zone.

Comment: Right, but this has nothing to do with hoisting at all.

Comment: Hoisting is the reason why the variable is in the scope of the inner function, even though the declaration is after the function is defined.

Comment: That also has nothing to do with hoisting - it's just the fact variables' validity is checked when referenced - which happens to happen with f is invoked which is _after_ the variable is defined. If `f` was an IIFE for example the code would throw. Hoisting is simply not the correct term for it.

Comment: The ES 2015 even explicitly mentions `var` statements are hoisted: "This is the case for var statements and the formal parameter lists of some non-strict functions"

Comment: @Benjamin: So, is hoisting defined as an *initialized* binding?

Comment: @FelixKling that's a good question, hoisting is only defined in the specification in notes and under the `HoistableDeclaration` construct. In notes it always treats hoisting as initialized binding (note in 12.1.5, 13.7.5.9, 14.1.3, 14.4.2, 18.2.1.2 - also mentions "hoisting conflicts" between var and let) - as for actual spec (not notes in the spec) we have `HoistableDeclaration` which is a function declaration or a generator declaration. It doesn't look like it's really that clear cut as the spec doesn't _actually_ define hoisting.

Comment: I've only actually seen it mean initialized binding before in esdiscuss and such, but I guess it's a new difference since in ES5 the two were indistinguishable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by Benjamin Gruenbaum, `let` and `const` don't hoist at all.

As a matter of fact, there are new rules that apply to `let` and `const`, such as the…

**temporal dead zone**

Now, if these were `var` declarations, everything would be clear. But with `let` and `const`, ES6 introduces a new concept of the [temporal dead zone.](http://jsrocks.org/2015/01/temporal-dead-zone-tdz-demystified/) This includes a new, subtle dynamic.

Let's have a look at two examples:

Hoisting classically would work in an example like this:

```
'use strict';
var x = 10;

console.log(x);
console.log(y); // This should NOT crash

var y = 5;
```

But if we were to replace the `var` declarations with `let` declarations, it would crash:

```
'use strict';
let x = 10;

console.log(x);
console.log(y); // This crashes: ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `y' before initialization

let y = 5;
```

Why does this crash?

Because unlike `var` assignments, accessing variables defined using `let` before the actual `let` statement is invalid (they are in the temporal dead zone).

**2. Temporal Dead Zone in this case**

In this case however, the temporal dead zone is not an issue. Why?

Because while we define the function with the `console.log(y)` statement beforehand, the actual function call and thus variable access only happens towards the end of the code. So the variable bindings are only evaluated at this point (thanks again, @BG):

```
'use strict';
let x = 10;
function f() {
   console.log(x);
   console.log(y); // This should not yet crash
}

let y = 5;
f(); // console.log(y) is only called here
```

If you were to reverse the order of `let y = 5;` and `f();`, your code would crash.

Comment: It's not hoisting - it's just the fact bindings are evaluated when the function is called and not before - the function is called which is after y is defined.

Comment: So that means the engine creates no reference to `y` at all before the `let y = 5;` statement? And thus, when a TDZ error is thrown, the engine checks to see it there is a `let` declaration later on?

Comment: The first part: Yes. The second part - it's the other way around, a TDZ error is thrown if the engine can't find a binding. In the case in question there is a binding already defined so there is no TDZ error thrown.

Comment: Right, I was just wondering how the engine knows the difference between no binding at all and a missing binding due to TDZ (these are technical details, I'm just curious as this does not seem to work as I expected :) ).

Comment: JavaScript isn't really interpreted line by line - the whole function body has to be read _first_ and bindings and order extracted. This is done because it is necessary for `var` bindings, `class` declarations and `function` declarations which _are_ hoisted.

Comment: Engines don't process things line by line. A binding is created for every variable in a given scope at the beginning, before evaluation is started, but for `let` and `const`, but binding is left uninitialized, whereas `var` initializes the binding to `undefined`. let/const bindings are initialized when the `let/const` lines are actually evaluated, and attempting to access an uninitialized binding will throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. There is still so much to understand…

Comment: I guess it depends on what you understand by "hoist". According to the spec, bindings for `let` and `const` are created (hoisted?) but not initialized. That's how the runtime knows that the binding is in a TDZ.